# Nested Objects are a String - Need them as Objects

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, object, express

I am using express-validator in node to validate my forms, once I am returned my validation result full of errors they pass through an object (this is what I have):

```
{ email: 
   { param: 'email',
     msg: 'Email address must be between 4-100 characters long, please try again.',
     value: '' },
  name: 
   { param: 'name',
     msg: 'Name must be between 3-20 characters long.',
     value: '' },
  password: 
   { param: 'password',
     msg: 'Password must include one lowercase character, one uppercase character, a number, and a special character.',
     value: '' },
  passwordc: 
   { param: 'passwordc',
     msg: 'Password must be between 8-50 characters long.',
     value: '' } }
```

The problem I have is that this is a "String" and unfortunately not of object type. I need to convert this into what it should be, an object with nested objects.

I cannot use JSON.parse because this is not valid JSON.

How can I change this string of objects, into an object? This is so that I can loop through and display the relevant errors.

Thanks for your help. P.S I am super stuck on this - so if you know the answer to this then lot's of brownie points from me to you. Cheers!

Comment: Your JSON is valid, Why can't you use `JSON.parse` in that case?

Comment: You can check this out with JSONLint, it is not valid. Valid JSON should have double quotes, not single, and also all keys should have double quotes around them too. The only way I can JSON.parse is after running way too many regular expressions, and that is not a good way because key names may change. I am really stumped with this!

Comment: I'm confused, this is a valid JavaScript object and not a string.

Comment: @str That's what! I've checked it in, http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/ and it seems to be perfect

Comment: I am confused too lol. If I run this object in gettype() it is a string, and displays as a string in the console, even though it's an object. I cannot run JSON.parse on it as is, because it is currently a string.

Comment: Are you receiving it in surrounded by quotes? The code above processes in JS as an `object` not a `string` in my browser.

Answer (score 1):

Ok this was really strange, and I have come to the bottom of this.

Basically there must be a bug/problem with the way express-validator is handing back objects with their new updates.

I have used their depreciated function validationErrors() which returns back an object which is an object - yay. As opposed to using their recommended setup: https://github.com/ctavan/express-validator#installation

This was returning me an object which was a typeof string (weird I know). I will let the developers know encase this is a bug, or perhaps due to my setup (node, express, react).

Thanks for the answers.

Answer (score 0):

I think, it is a problem with JSON notation. The current string that you are getting is not in the required format. You need to put double quotes around property names and double quotes for strings instead of single quotes. That should get your `JSON.parse` to work.

To root cause it, you got to focus where are you getting this JSON from and make sure it emits a proper JSON format.

Also, if your code is creating this JSON, you would rather not want to add newlines and padding to reduce size. You can always use http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/ (or others) to see them in friendly format.

Hope this helps!